# Download commit messages from project in GitHub

Tags: github

I have a project in GitHub and during the last years I have committed several changes to the project. In each commit I was adding a small text about the commit (e.g. fix problem with function A).

Is there a way to download all the commits that I have committed so far ?. I don't want to download the changes of the code of each commit, just only the text that I was writing.. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you did the work from your local Git project, then GitHub does not have to be involved at all here.  You can checkout the branch in question, fetch update it, and then use `git log`:

```
git checkout master           # assuming contributions go to the master branch
git pull origin master
git log --author="yaylitzis"  # replace 'yaylitzis' with your actual username
```

The pull is required because perhaps your local branch does not have all your commits for some reason.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I managed to see all the commit history from the IDE (NetBeans) that I use to build my project.

Answer (score 2):

GitHub has an API for that.

[https://api.github.com/repos/*(username)*/*(repository)*/commits](https://api.github.com/repos/torvalds/linux/commits)

See [REST API v3: Commits](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/)

> List commits on a repository 
>   `GET /repos/:owner/:repo/commits`

You can then just read all `message` keys in the `commit` objects

**Edit:**

If you try to do that on a private repository, you have to make an authentication first.

Basic example with `curl`:

```sh
curl -u username:password https://api.github.com/repos/username/repository/commits
```

More on that: [Other Authentication Methods](https://developer.github.com/v3/auth/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply (+1 from me), however in my case your approach doesn't apply as the project is private and I am getting a message `"Not Found"`

Comment: @yaylitzis That's actually not a problem either. See my edit